# Как назвать жителя города Ессентуки?

Tags: этнохороним

Как называют жителя города Ессентуки? И жительницу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ессентучане, ессентучанин, ессентучанка.

А в чем сложность или сомнения? Вроде не вызывает затруднений.

Comment: Спасибо. Казалось, что иначе. Почему то это простое решение в голову не пришло.